# Dropdown should to be populated by the document values not the document name

Tags: skyve

as you may be able to see from my image below, my drop-down is populated by the display name not the value from the table bindings.  Did I miss something or did I get the Document definition wrong?

```
<association type="aggregation" name="noteType">
        <displayName>NoteType</displayName>
        <documentName>NoteType</documentName>
    </association>
```

is it missing something to tell it to use the binding?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Dropdown to be populated by the document values not the document name]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

good question.

In the situation where you are associating an object instance from another object instance (in this case perhaps from a *Note* to a *NoteType*), the default widget Skyve will propose for the view will be a *lookupDescription* (the drop down in your screenshot). *NoteType* is a document which may have many attributes - the *lookupDescription* widget has a *descriptionBinding* - this is usually set to *bizKey* but can also be set directly to one of the attributes of *NoteType*. The *bizKey* in a document defaults to be the same as the document's singular alias until you set it, resulting in what you see above.

Take for example that *NoteType* has 3 attributes, an code (text), a typeName (text) and a description (memo).
e.g., Note Types:

| code | typeName | description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NWS | news | a news item for the team |
| ALT | alert | an urgent alert |
| COM | comment | a general comment |
| RAN | random | a fun item not related to work |

- in this case it is not obvious what to show in the drop down or *lookupDescription*. Perhaps you may want to use the *code* attribute ("NWS", "ALT" ...) or the *typeName* attribute (e.g. "news", "alert" ... ) in the drop down, or a mashup of several of the attributes of *NoteType* like *typeName* and *code* (e.g. "NWS (news)", "ALT (alert)" ...).

Whereas in Java you can specify a *.toString()* method, in Skyve you specify a *bizKey* - see https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/documents/#bizkey.

For this example, I could specify the *NoteType* document *bizKey* attribute like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<document name="NoteType" ...>
    <persistent name="NoteType"/>
    <singularAlias>Note Type</singularAlias>
    <pluralAlias>Note Types</pluralAlias>
    <bizKey expression="{code} ({name})" />
    <attributes>
        <text name="code" >
            <displayName>Code</displayName>
            <length>3</length>
        </text>
        <text name="typeName" >
            <displayName>Type Name</displayName>
            <length>50</length>
        </text>
        <memo name="description" >
            <displayName>Description</displayName>
        </memo>
    </attributes>
</document>
```

where *bizKey* has the expression "{code} ({name})" yielding "NWS (news)", "ALT (alert)" ... this uses Skyve expressions which will be re-evaluated as part of the bean lifecycle and saved as the special database field *bizKey*.

You can also define the *bizKey* in Java  - for an example of this, check the Contact document (Contact.xml file) in the admin module in your project.

The *bizKey* attribute is required by Skyve - so when you create a project in Skyve Foundry, the *bizKey* attribute in the project xml is generated to default to the singular alias (or document name) - in your case "NoteType" to make sure it will have a value.

The *bizKey* is required by Skyve so that there is always a way for the application to refer to an instance of a document. This is especially important for no-code situations where the developer may not yet have got around to specifying things precisely but wants to be able to start to use the application as a proof of concept.

The *bizKey* attribute is persisted (saved) in the database for performance reasons - so that Skyve can rapidly retrieve and filter rows based on *bizKey* values, rather than attempting to calculate them as a derived expression (which would require conversion of expressions or Java code to dialect-specific SQL and also add extra processing every time *bizKey* values were retrieved).

This means that if you have created data with a different *bizKey* definition, you'll need to resave your *NoteType* records. You can do this easily by:

- signing in to your Skyve application as an administrator (or the setup/bootstrap user if you have one)
- navigate to admin->Devops->Data Maintenance and choose the Data Refresh tab
- select the NoteType document, choose the Option "Save" and press "Refresh Persisted Document Data"

For reference:

https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/documents/#documentxml-sections

https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/expressions/

https://skyvers.github.io/skyve-dev-guide/skyve-persistence-mechanisms/